# Chartjs bar chart trying to get labels from datasets

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to implement chartJS bar chart and use the legend to filter bars.
I want to set the labels list to be empty because this allows me to remove bars clearly.
I am looking for a way to set the ticks with labels on X axis, since it is empty from text now.

JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/m1eorjwv/1/

```
   var options = {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'red',
          data: [12],
          borderWidth: 1
        },  
        {
          label: 'blue',
          data: [7],
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            reverse: false,
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
   }
```

Thanks a lot, Alon

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in your post and **don't just 
include a link to jsFiddle**. Links rot, and your post should stand alone from any other resource; 
 this question will lose any value to future visitors if jsFiddle is blocked or goes away in the future!

Comment: I don't understand the need properly, can you please elaborate more.

Comment: Could you add a diagram of your expected output?

Comment: I want to be able to filter bars from my bar charts.
I am sending each bar as seperate data object in data list.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this, here is the ansert:

```
enter code here
code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ehacujny